# Force a process to update cwd after mount?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, mount, redis

Redis is dumping snapshots to device that is rapidly running out of space.

I've tried mounting a larger device to the snapshot directory, but Redis continues to dump snapshots to the smaller device.

Is there any way to force redis to use the new directory without restarting the service?

Comment: The [Shutdown command](http://redis.io/commands/shutdown) I believe is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some configuration parameters that can be changed on the fly using the [CONFIG SET](http://redis.io/commands/config-set) command. From version 2.2, you can change the working directory at runtime with:

```
redis-cli> config get dir
redis-cli> config set /path/to/new/dir
```